# Traefik Basic Auth

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have recently started using Traefik with Docker and I must say it is fantastic. The trouble I am having at the moment is when I apply basic auth middleware to my Traefik dashboard and then go to load the dashboard, it constantly prompts for my the username and password on an endless loop and I can never get to the dashboard. However, it works perfectly fine without the basic auth and I can load my dashboard just fine. Please can anyone help with this? It has been driving me crazy for the last few days. Please see my samples below. (Note for the password hash I have tried both with and without an extra dollar sign at the beginning and neither work). Thank you in advance.

My Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/user/traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yaml:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=insecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=api-auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.api-auth.basicauth.users=admin:$$..."
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: "web"
```

My Traefik.yml file

```
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    network: "web" # Custom docker network
    exposedByDefault: false 

entryPoints:
  insecure:
    address: ":80"
  secure:
    address: ":443"

api:
  dashboard: true
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems related to the hash password.
ALL `$` signs must be escaped by another `$`, not the first one at the beginning.
Moreover, not every crypt functions are handled.
Try to generate a password with this: `echo $(htpasswd -nb user password) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g` as indicated in https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/basicauth/#users

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the issue as I also discovered on another forum I posted to. There were a couple $ symbols that needed to escape in the hash and then it worked perfectly.